# Facing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate issue while implementing SSL two way authentication

Tags: java, ssl, network-programming, openssl, keytool

I am working on **SSL two way authentication using self signed certificates**.
I have created two keystores for **client(client-keystore.jks)** and **server(server-keystore.jks)**, Exported the certificates from both the keystores and imported client certificate into server keystore and server certificate into client keystore. and updated required connector entry in the **server.xml**,added both the certificates to the java trust store **cacerts**.

Java Client code:

```
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS", "SUN");
            trustStore.load(SSLImplemetation.class.getResourceAsStream("C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/security/cacerts"), "changeit".toCharArray());
            String alg = KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory fac = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(alg);
            fac.init(trustStore);


            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS", "SUN");
            keystore.load(SSLImplemetation.class.getResourceAsStream("<dir path>/client-keystore.jks"), "test".toCharArra());
            String keyAlg = KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            KeyManagerFactory keyFac = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(keyAlg);
            keyFac.init(keystore, "test".toCharArray());

                SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS", "SunJSSE");
            ctx.init(keyFac.getKeyManagers(),fac.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

            SslContextedSecureProtocolSocketFactory secureProtocolSocketFactory = new SslContextedSecureProtocolSocketFactory(ctx);
            Protocol.registerProtocol("https", new Protocol("https", (ProtocolSocketFactory) secureProtocolSocketFactory, 8443));

            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost("<rest service url>");

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
StringEntity params =new StringEntity(obj.toString());  

     request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
     request.setEntity(params);
     HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
     System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
```

server.xml:

```
<Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
             clientAuth="true" sslProtocol="TLS"
             keystoreFile="<dir path>/server-keystore.jks" keystorePass="test"
             truststoreFile="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
             truststorePass="changeit" />
```

I am new to SSl,so bit confused.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works fine for me, after creating two client and server keystore and place both the certificate into java truststore, I have used below code for SSL Mutual Authentication.

```
static final private String KEY_STORE = "D:/sslcertificates/client-keystore.jks";
    static final private String KEY_STORE_TYPE = "JKS";
    static final private String KEY_STORE_PASS = "test";

        public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException{

          try {
              URL url = new URL("<rest service url>");   
              HttpsURLConnection  conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

```
                    public boolean verify(String hostname,
                                          javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
                        if (hostname.equals("<hostname>")) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });


                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
              try
              {
              KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509","SunJSSE");
              KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEY_STORE_TYPE);
              File cert = new File(KEY_STORE);
              InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(cert);
              ks.load(stream, KEY_STORE_PASS.toCharArray());
              stream.close();
              kmf.init(ks,KEY_STORE_PASS.toCharArray());

              SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
              context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(),null, new SecureRandom());            
              SSLSocketFactory factory = context.getSocketFactory();               
              conn.setSSLSocketFactory(factory);

              }
              catch(Exception e)
              {
                  System.out.println(e);
              }

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
             obj.put("id","abc");
             obj.put("name","surya");
             obj.put( "domain","IT");     
             String input=obj.toString();

         //send request to server....            

             OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
             os.write(input.getBytes());
             os.flush();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }
             System.out.println("Response code: "+conn.getResponseCode());
              System.out.println("Response message: "+conn.getResponseMessage());
            conn.disconnect();

          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

          } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

         }

        }
```

Server.xml

```
 <Connector
   protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
   port="8443" maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true"   SSLEnabled="true"
   clientAuth="true" sslProtocol="TLS"
    keystoreFile="<dir path>/server-keystore.jks" keystorePass="test"/>
```

**NOTE: Set HostnameVerifier in HttpsURLConnection object and CN of client and server keystore should be host name.**

Please suggest, if any better solution.